# Confused on setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use setInterval() to get the newest datas and draw something at set intervals.But in IE,it only works one time,I searched it in google,it says the cache of IE may be a problem,so I added a time stamp to my url like this:

```
url+"?"+Math.random();
```

But it still doesn't work,or I made some mistakes?

I changed another way to write my function,the former codes are:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
    autoRefreshFunction(some parameters){
        var interval=setInterval(
                         function(){
                             main function that gets data and draw
                         },time_interval);
    }
}
```

It only work one time in IE,but chrome is ok.

The new codes are:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
    var interval=setInterval(
                     function(){
                         main function that gets data and draw
                     },time_interval);
}
```

It works in IE,so I am confused about the difference between this two method.

Comment: the interval variable lives only in the context of the autoRefreshFunction (not declared globally) so when the memory for this function is cleared, so is the interval. Try to either declare "interval" globally or use the 2nd code.

Comment: I cannot tell what you're asking here.  Can you clarify with real code not pseudo code and be more specific about what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: @Cystack - you are correct about the lifetime of the variable `interval`, but that does not affect the actual interval timer.  It keeps going either way.

Comment: what does the autoRefreshFunction do?

Comment: You should add some code that updates a textbox on the screen each time the function fires.  If it is firing you can stop worrying about setInterval and focus on the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
```

You're closing the parenthesis to `ready` too soon.  I think you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

IE may have been confused by that.  Also, in your original code you had:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
    autoRefreshFunction(some parameters){ //<----- what's this?
        var interval=setInterval(
                         function(){
                             main function that gets data and draw
                         },time_interval);
    }
```

It looks like you were sort of defining a function called `autoRefreshFunction`, but incorrectly since you forgot the function keyword.

I think the end result should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval=setInterval(
                     function(){
                         main function that gets data and draw
                     },time_interval);
}
```